# Spawn CMD with relative path

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to get MD to spawn with a relative path, I cant seem to find anyone who has done it.

My solution does not work as it try to execute c:/Program

> stderr: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

**My Code**

```
        var path = require('path');
        var batpath = path.resolve(path.dirname(process.execPath), 'script.bat');
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
             ls    = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', batpath]);

        ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('stdout: ' + data);
        });

        ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('stderr: ' + data);
        });

        ls.on('exit', function (code) {
            console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
        });
```

Comment: can you show us the contents of `script.bat` ?

Comment: Its not loading the script its just trying to load the start of the first path

Comment: I'd still like to see the contents, and also the value of `batpath`